# vb.net 2010 Listview

Tags: vb.net, listview

istview1 selected index= listview2 selected index

if i select an item in listview1, then listviews2's index will be the same sa listview1.
how am I suppose to do that? help me please.

Comment: please restructure your question...post more detail or any code that you have tried

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)  Handles ListView1.SelectedIndexChanged

  '// Loop through in case MultiSelect is on
  For i as Integer = 0 to ListView1.Items.Count - 1
          ListView2.Items(i).Selected = ListView1.Items(i).Selected
  Next i

  '// or if multiselect is not on... changing index will uncheck everything else
   Try
       ListView2.Items(ListView1.SelectedIndices(0)).Selected = True
   Catch ex as Exception '// catch means nothing was selcted in first list
       If ListView2.SelectedItems.Count > 0 then '// clear if necessary
          ListView2.SelectedItems(0).Selected = False
       End if
   End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: accept the answer if it worked for you